# Canvas size in Adobe flash for Web Designing

Tags: flash, web, adobe, photoshop

I just want to know what canvas size do i make my Adobe Photoshop file while designing a website so that later on when i import my Adobe Photoshop file to Adobe Flash it should open perfectly in all browsers.

I have tried using 1000 x 700 as canvas size but still a little space is left empty on the right hand side when i open the website on my browser.

Comment: By Adobe Photoshop file i mean to say my psd file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no default size for working with websites in Photoshop, it all depends on the usage. Today most designers will work with a variety of sizes that respond to the device/browser size. A good indication of some of the more common sizes can be found in frameworks such as bootstrap, and have breakpoints along the lines of:

Large screen:         1400px

Tablet portrait:      1024px

Smartphones portrait: 320px

These are just examples, but personally if I was designing for a desktop view I would work on a 1400px basis. Any reason why you are designing for flash by the way? It is no longer the standard way to create a website as there is minimum support.

For more on common screensizes: http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_display.asp
For more on common responsive grids: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/

Comment: 1400px width would do fine for some screens but what about for monitors which have resolution upto 1600px or less then 1400px...some space will be left in that case...i need to do something generic that fits in every browser....and btw your other question that why i,m using flash....well Flash supports a variety of animations that cannot be done by bootstrap or any other software.

Comment: E.g take a look at this website : http://www.bryanjamesdesign.co.uk/ ....the various animations can be done only and only with flash this is what i believe...please correct me if i,m wrong.

Comment: Actually @steve, you are DEAD wrong... Flash doesn't exist at all on the site you listed above. This is all done with either CSS3 or jQuery animation. Right click on the page, view source, and then search for .swf. Nothing. Now...For a mind blowing exercise on YOUR part, visit here: http://www.creativebloq.com/css3/animation-with-css3-712437.. And in case you miss it on that list, my personal favorite: http://www.clicktorelease.com/code/css3dclouds/

Comment: Hi Steve, Flash is not used at all for websites anymore, it is non supported by many devices and is used only for suited web applicatations. Using CSS3 animations and transitions based in a framework such as bootstrap is the way to go, as per my answer above. You can create any flash animation in this way and it will work on many devices and browsers. Using a responsive grid will also solve any browser issues you are having. Please mark as correct if this has been helpful.

Comment: Okay thanx i,ve been looking for the secret behind all this awesome web designing...and i think i finally found the answer...and its CSS3 I guess...i was trying to learn flash but i guess i,ll quit flash and try to focus on CSS3 from now onwards. Thanks @Phlume.

Comment: Its a much better direction to go down trust me, there is a lot of support out there should you ever get stuck with it as well.